Extracting text that duplicates in two separate columns
I have a df:
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| John     | Doe      |
| Tom      | Tom      |
| Sally    | Mae      |
| Mark     | Mark     |
| Jack     | Jack     |

I want to extract all the names that appear in Column A and Column B as duplicates. For example, the final df should look like:
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| Tom      | Tom      |
| Mark     | Mark     |
| Jack     | Jack     |

I have tried .duplicated(subset=["Column A", "Column B"]) and .drop_duplicates, but these only present the duplicates from each row, not each column.

Try:
mask = df["Column A"] == df["Column B"]
print(df[mask])

Prints:
  Column A Column B
1      Tom      Tom
3     Mark     Mark
4     Jack     Jack


THANK YOU, FINALLY!! lol, such a simple solution, and I've been searching for 3-4 days.
